# PFSense as linode Firewall

Tags: pfsense, linode

I am building my master’s final project and was planning on having pfsense as the main firewall to monitor and manage all the instances. I chose Linode, well due to cheap and network chuck’s recommendation.

I’m still relatively new to cloud and networking, so not sure what I need to do here.

5 instances are there out which 1 has PFsense installed and working on it.
Linode’s Firewall, from what I understood keeps all the machines under the firewall.
from the videos I have seen, it shows either the netgear build pfsense being connected in the h/w
Chatgpt gives some idea but either I’m not phrasing the correct question or I’m thinking of a weird thing.

Am I supposed to configure VLANs in PFsense, create subnets and then assign IPs from those subnets to the virtual machines or is there a way to configure the gateways in the vms and then connect them directly.

Answer (score 1):

With IPv6, this would be easily possible – request a /64 or even /56 to be routed to the pfSense VM, then create a Linodes VLAN to connect it directly to the other VMs and use the /64 for addressing that VLAN.

Though from what I remember, Linode's VLAN doesn't really show up as a tagged 802.1Q VLAN on your VMs – instead it shows up as a whole separate 'physical' Ethernet interface like eth2. (The host machine handles the VLAN tagging so you don't see it.)

With IPv4, however, I don't think you'll be able to do this "properly" on Linode. You can have other linodes route their outbound traffic through the pfSense VM, yes... but you can't have Linode route their *inbound* traffic through it. The VMs' public IP addresses will always be routed directly through the VMs themselves.

(Especially in the datacenters that have been switched to the "new" network architecture; it *may* have worked in the "old" network that was just a flat subnet that used ARP, but not in the new L3-routed architecture.)

You can still set up a network though using entirely private IPv4 addresses and NAT (using Linode's VLAN feature to isolate the other VMs from direct Internet access), but you'll be limited to just one public IPv4 address for the whole thing; the addresses belonging to the other VMs would just be wasted.

(Well, to be fair, that *is* how many real-life networks unfortunately have to work – with all servers having to share one IP address... so it wouldn't be inaccurate.)

Comment: Honestly, this helps a lot, I mean a lot. I will have to give it a try to see, if it works and I am hoping it works. But thank you for sharing this, I will post here again for what I was able to figure out.